# Display 3 posts with different HTML markup in Wordpress using a loop

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I want to be able to display 3 posts from the same category on my index.php page, but due to the way my site's HTML/CSS is coded I'm having some difficulty understanding the correct way to go about doing this using a loop (as the code for the divs being used are not the same for all three sections, it's using different CSS styles to achieve a layered effect/look ).

Here is the HTML code.

```
<div id="first-story" class="story">
<div class="content">
<h3 class="story-heading">Headline 1</h3>
    <ul>
       <li>Nullam sit amet scelerisque est. </li>   
       <li>Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sed nisi nunc, faucibus rutrum mauris. </li>
       <li>Nullam iaculis lorem ut tortor ullamco per aliquet. Integer id leo non mauris pulvinar gravida vitae a enim. </li>
       <li>Nullam sit amet scelerisque est.</li>
    </ul>   
        <a class="learnmore" href="#"><img src="img/button-learnmore.png"></a></div>
    <div class="edge"></div>
</div>

<div id="second-story" class="story">
    <div class="content">
       <h3 class="story-heading">Headline 2</h3>
       <p>Paragraph text</p>
       <a class="learnmore" href="#"><img src="img/button-learnmore.png"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="third-story" class="story">
    <div class="edge"></div>
    <div class="content">Headline 3</div>
            <ul>
               <li>List item</li>
            </ul>
            <a class="learnmore" href="#"><img src="img/button-learnmore.png"></a></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: kinda strange but the only way would be to run an if within the loop. On the first count of the loop do post 1, on the second loop and so on. I haven't actually worked with Wordpress so I don't know the context of your 'looping'. Javascript, PHP, ?

Comment: @Graham.Fraser It's using the Wordpress loop, basically PHP code used to display posts. You can read more about it on their codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick, nasty and will get the job done (Obviously need to add the_content(); etc)

```
<?php 

$i = 1;
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if ($i == 1) { ?>
    <div id="first-story" class="story">
        <div class="content">  
            <h3 class="story-heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <ul>
               <li>Nullam sit amet scelerisque est. </li>   
               <li>Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sed nisi nunc, faucibus rutrum mauris. </li>
               <li>Nullam iaculis lorem ut tortor ullamco per aliquet. Integer id leo non mauris pulvinar gravida vitae a enim. </li>
               <li>Nullam sit amet scelerisque est.</li>
            </ul>   
            <a class="learnmore" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?></a>"><img src="img/button-learnmore.png"></a></div>
            <div class="edge"></div>
        </div>
<?php } elseif ($i == 2) { ?>

                <div id="second-story" class="story">
                    <div class="content">
                       <h3 class="story-heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                       <p>Paragraph text</p>
                       <a class="learnmore" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="img/button-learnmore.png"></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<?php } else { ?>
                <div id="third-story" class="story">
                    <div class="edge"></div>
                    <div class="content"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                            <ul>
                               <li>List item</li>
                            </ul>
                            <a class="learnmore" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="img/button-learnmore.png"></a></div>
                </div>
<?php } ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```