# Show 3 latest posts, each one with different HTML markup

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i'm trying to show the three latest posts from a custom post type, each one with different HTML markup. I googled it and i tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593598/display-3-posts-with-different-html-markup-in-wordpress-using-a-loop) and also [this method](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83702/display-3-posts-with-different-html-markup-using-a-loop) but neither of them worked. Here is the code now from the loop

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'latest-products' ) ); ?>
  <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
     <h1>This is the title</h1>
     <p>This is a paragraph</p>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

and i want to swap the tags in the second post

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<h1>This is the title</h1>
```

and on the third post i want to be the same as the first.

I couldn't achieve it with those links that told you. How can i do it? Maybe i'm doing something wrong with the php cod from those links

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'latest-products' ) ); ?>
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
     <?php if ($i == 0 || $i == 2): ?>
         <h1 style="color:green">This is the title</h1>
         <p>This is a paragraph</p>
     <?php else: ?>
         <h1 style="color:red">This is the title</h1>
         <p>This is a paragraph</p>
     <?php endif; ?>
     <?php $i++ ?>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: you've just made my day